# Wrap every three items in a div, complete even if the element count does not divide by 3

Tags: php, foreach

I'm working through a fairly simple `foreach` loop which outputs a list of links:

```
foreach ($pages as $page){
   echo '<a href="'.$page['guid'].'">'.$page['post_title'].'</a>';
}
```

At present there are `8` items being output.

I need to wrap the items so that they appear as such:

```
<div class="grid one-third">
   <ul>
      <li>Sitemap</li>
      <li>Sitemap</li>
      <li>Sitemap</li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="grid one-third">
   <ul>
      <li>Sitemap</li>
      <li>Sitemap</li>
      <li>Sitemap</li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="grid one-third">
   <ul>
      <li>Sitemap</li>
      <li>Sitemap</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

So as you can see, it is wrapping `every third item` in `.grid .one-third` and a new `ul`

But I don't want to match it based on a counter of `3` because this would fall over when the number of items are not divisible by three (e.g `8` items).

I am trying to use the modulo operator to allow me to separate every 3 items but I seem to be getting nested divs instead of closing the div in the correct place. Here is my solution so far:

```
foreach ($pages as $page){
$page = (array)$page;
   echo '<li><a href="'.$page['guid'].'">'.$page['post_title'].'</a></li>';
   if ($counter && $counter % 3 === 0){
      echo '</ul><div class="grid one-third"><ul>';
   }
   $counter++;
}
```

Any ideas how I can make this correctly wrap every 3 items (or wrap at end) in `<div class="grid one-third><ul>` ?

Comment: array_chunk($array,3)

Comment: I like @splash58's solution: convert your linear array to an array of arrays, and then use two nested `foreach()` loops.

Comment: Yes. It gives fine structure and position of wrapping elements

Comment: @splash58 can you show your solution in line with the code above? I'm having trouble working out exactly how `array_chunk` divides the data

Comment: @Francesca it is not with your data. That code builds a table from an array of tds, but, i hope, the idea is clear https://eval.in/411954

Answer (score 1):

You just need some extra conditions at the end of the loop to check where the loop broke.

e.g.

```
while(...) {
    ... logic to start a new div if necessary
    ... output a row of data
    ... logic to end a full div
}
if (loop ended with open div) {
   ... end the final div
}
```